# Ubuntu and Qt creator keyboard layout change problem

Tags: keyboard, 14.04, keyboard-layout, qt-creator, qt5

When I run Qt Creator on my Ubuntu 14.04 with `English` layout, it always types in English and it won't change if I change my layout to other language. In front, when I run Qt Creator with `Persian` layout, it only lets me to write in Persian and it does not change with keyboard layout changing. 
I have searched a lot, But I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: I have the same problem. Somebody tried to switch to KDE from GNOME based on this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/446796/cant-change-keyboard-layout-in-some-qt-programs